# Logloss of binary classifier with constant prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, cost-based-optimizer

What is the `logloss` of a binary classifier if we choose a constant prediction `f=0.5`?

Is this development of the equation correct?

```
logloss = (1/N) * sum(-y*log(f)-(1-y)*log(1-f))
logloss(y=0) = -(1-0)*log(1-f) = -log(f)
logloss(y=1) = -1*log(f) = -log(f)
// That is either ground true y is 0 or 1 the cost is -log(f)
logloss = (1/N) * N * (-log(f)) = -log(f) = -log(5) = 0.69315
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214177/scaling-up-random-guess-benchmark-of-log-loss, on cross validated stack exchange.

Comment: But, yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is a non graded question on a quiz from coursera (How to win a data science competition). The corrector of the coursera quiz says that 0.69315 is not a correct answer and I do not get why?